# Find all combinations in a 3x3 matrix following some rules

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Given a 3x3 matrix:

```
|1 2 3|  
|4 5 6|  
|7 8 9|
```

I'd like to calculate all the combinations by connecting the numbers in this matrix following these rules:

- the combinations width are between 3 and 9
- use one number only once
- you can only connect adjacent numbers

Some examples: 123, 258, 2589, 123654, etc.
For example 1238 is not a good combination because 3 and 8 are not adjacent. The 123 and the 321 combination is not the same.
I hope my description is clear.
If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Actually I don't know how to start :D. Thanks

Comment: To start, I'd look up recursion and perhaps breadth or depth first searching while keeping track of 'visited' nodes.

Comment: Alternatively if you can use e.g. clojure, scheme or prolog then they have automatic constraint-based solvers built in. e.g. you'll find plenty of example Sudoku solvers in clojure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a search problem. You can just use straightforward depth-first-search with recursive programming to quickly solve the problem. Something like the following:

```
func search(matrix[N][M], x, y, digitsUsed[10], combination[L]) {
    if length(combination) between 3 and 9 {
       add this combination into your solution
    }

    // four adjacent directions to be attempted
    dx = {1,0,0,-1}
    dy = {0,1,-1,0}
    for i = 0; i < 4; i++ {
       next_x = x + dx[i]
       next_y = y + dy[i]
       if in_matrix(next_x, next_y) and not digitsUsed[matrix[next_x][next_y]] {
           digitsUsed[matrix[next_x][next_y]] = true
           combination += matrix[next_x][next_y]
           search(matrix, next_x, next_y, digitsUsed, combination)

           // At this time, sub-search starts with (next_x, next_y) has been completed.
           digitsUsed[matrix[next_x][next_y]] = false
       }
   }
}
```

So you could run search function for every single grid in the matrix, and every combinations in your solution are different from each other because they start from different grids.

In addition, we don't need to record the status which indicates one grid in the matrix has or has not been traversed because every digit can be used only once, so grids which have been traversed will never be traversed again since their digits have been already contained in the combination.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation in Python 3 as a a recursive depth-first exploration:

```py
def find_combinations(data, min_length, max_length):
    # Matrix of booleans indicating what values have been used
    visited = [[False for _ in row] for row in data]
    # Current combination
    comb = []
    # Start recursive algorithm at every possible position
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            # Add initial combination element and mark as visited
            comb.append(data[i][j])
            visited[i][j] = True
            # Start recursive algorithm
            yield from find_combinations_rec(data, min_length, max_length, visited, comb, i, j)
            # After all combinations with current element have been produced remove it
            visited[i][j] = False
            comb.pop()

def find_combinations_rec(data, min_length, max_length, visited, comb, i, j):
    # Yield the current combination if it has the right size
    if min_length <= len(comb) <= max_length:
        yield comb.copy()
    # Stop the recursion after reaching maximum length
    if len(comb) >= max_length:
        return
    # For each neighbor of the last added element
    for i2, j2 in ((i - 1, j), (i, j - 1), (i, j + 1), (i + 1, j)):
        # Check the neighbor is valid and not visited
        if i2 < 0 or i2 >= len(data) or j2 < 0 or j2 >= len(data[i2]) or visited[i2][j2]:
            continue
        # Add neighbor and mark as visited
        comb.append(data[i2][j2])
        visited[i2][j2] = True
        # Produce combinations for current starting sequence
        yield from find_combinations_rec(data, min_length, max_length, visited, comb, i2, j2)
        # Remove last added combination element
        visited[i2][j2] = False
        comb.pop()

# Try it
data = [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]
min_length = 3
max_length = 9
for comb in find_combinations(data, min_length, max_length):
    print(c)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 5, 4, 7]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at all the combinations and take the connected ones:

```py
import itertools

def coords(n):
    """Coordinates of number n in the matrix."""
    return (n - 1) // 3, (n - 1) % 3

def adjacent(a, b):
    """Check if a and b are adjacent in the matrix."""
    ai, aj = coords(a)
    bi, bj = coords(b)
    return abs(ai - bi) + abs(aj - bj) == 1

def connected(comb):
    """Check if combination is connected."""
    return all(adjacent(a, b) for a, b in zip(comb, comb[1:]))

for width in range(3, 10):
    for comb in itertools.permutations(range(1, 10), width):
        if connected(comb):
            print(comb)
```

Comment: Thank you @gus!
That seems fine for me, but I would like to code this algorithm in Swift(that I didn't mention in the description, my bad). My main problem is that I simply don't get this `return all(adjacent(a, b) for a, b in zip(comb, comb[1:]))`  line of code. I don't know Python, and this line is soooo confusing. I understand the concept, but can't figure out how this line works exactly, and how to "translate" it to Swift.

Comment: Another way to say the same thing would be `all(adjacent(comb[i], comb[i+1]) for i in range(len(comb)-1)))`. It returns true if every two numbers that are adjacent in `comb` are also adjacent in the matrix. I don't know Swift, but this line might not be the hardest to translate. The tricky part here is hidden in the `itertools.permutations` call, and if you don't have something similar in Swift you'll have to implement it yourself or use a different approach.